# C# Selenium - How to Uniquily match webpage using a text

Tags: c#, regex, selenium, webdriver

I'm working on a website where I want to match a page using a unique string in it. Currently, I have two pages which I match using Regex. But I want to use text for matching the other pages.

What I've done so far is:

```
//This is the PageMatch attribute I'm using for the page.
[PageTitle("Some Text...")]
```

And is implemented as below:

```
public class PageTitleAttribute : PageMatchAttribute
    {
        protected string interviewTitle;

        public PageTitleAttribute(string title)
        {
            interviewTitle = title;
        }

        public override Func<IWebDriver, bool> PageMatchFunction()
        {
            return driver => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/h3")).Text.Contains(interviewTitle);
        }       
    }
```

It is not able to find the page handler ..
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are exactly asking?

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on how the page is written I guess. We use PageObject patterns and I use `xpath` for identifying the page title. Most of my page title looks like the following:

```
div class="gbl-table-wrapper ui-widget sitemap-menu">
  <div class="mod-header gbl-wrapper">
   <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

And, I use `//*[.='Title']` to uniquely identify that page. This `xpath` is very convenient which does a regex search of the whole page and find the element matching the text `Title`

If you want to stick to your plan then best way would be to use `FindElements()` method and find the element you want out of the list . That can a performance issue

```
_driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//h3")).ToList().Any(element => element.Text.Contains("Something"));
```

you need to import `using System.Linq;` for using linq

Hope this helps

Comment: You don't need the `ToList`. `FindElements` returns a `ReadOnlyCollection` which inherits from `List`.